# Mylyn jira in eclipse not work, there is always error

Tags: eclipse

I download last eclipse, and want to use jira in mylyn, but there always is error, I installed tasktop but seems also not right, Who can help solve what, thank you brother

Answer (score 0):

1. *Help > Install New Software...*
2. *Work with:* http://update.atlassian.com/atlassian-eclipse-plugin/rest/e3.7
3. Select *Atlassian Connector*
4. Click *Next*, the rest is self-explanatory